# How Can I A Threshold Image of a Salience Map?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-thresholding

I currently have the salience map of an image below, the spectral saliency and fine grained saliency images are below obtained by the following code:

```
import cv2

imgpath = r'Content Image.jpg'
image = cv2.imread(imgpath)

width = 350
height = 450
dim = (width, height)
 
# resize image
resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

saliency = cv2.saliency.StaticSaliencySpectralResidual_create()
(success, saliencyMap) = saliency.computeSaliency(resized)
saliencyMap = (saliencyMap * 255).astype("uint8")
cv2.imshow("Image", resized)
cv2.imshow("Output", saliencyMap)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

saliency = cv2.saliency.StaticSaliencyFineGrained_create()
(success, saliencyMap) = saliency.computeSaliency(resized)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

All of these make sense and I understand why they were obtained.

However, when I try to get the threshold map using the code below:

```
ret, threshMap = cv2.threshold(saliencyMap.astype("uint8"), 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow("Image", resized)
cv2.imshow("Output", saliencyMap)
cv2.imshow("Thresh", threshMap)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I obtain the following image:

[image]

Not quite sure why this is the case since I'm pretty sure I've following everything that I have found online, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by treshold map? You mean the thresholded binary image of OTSU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`saliencyMap` has values between 0 and 1. You need to rescale the values to 0-255 range.
Then, decide if you want otsu threshold or manual threshold. The given value `120` has no effect on Otsu binarization method as itself automatically determines the threshold value.

```
ret, threshMap = cv2.threshold((saliencyMap * 255).astype('uint8'), 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow("Image", resized)
cv2.imshow("Output", saliencyMap)
cv2.imshow("Thresh", threshMap)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

output Otsu binarization:

[image: otsu thresholded]

Or manual value `120` input for threshold

```
ret, threshMap = cv2.threshold((saliencyMap * 255).astype('uint8'), 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

[image: Manual 120 value threshold]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. One thing I haven't quite got my head around is how can I use otsu thresholding? What benefit does it have over manual thresholding?

Comment: yes you can check the opencv website. `Since we are working with bimodal images, Otsu's algorithm tries to find a threshold value (t) which minimizes the weighted within-class variance given by the relation:`
So with Otsu you don't have to put in any thresholding value. From the histogram chart of values, in layman terms, it detects value that causes the least variance in image if chosen. It works pretty well for most images depending on your use case of course.

Comment: This is awesome and I definitely value not needing to put in a threshold value to check and keep on iterating through until I get a "good" picture.